# Pyzbar decode: TypeError: cannot unpack not-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, typeerror, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar

i am making a barcode reader with pyzbar and opencv but when i use **decode** function from **pyzbar.pyzbar** i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\galax\Documents\barcodeScanner\barcodeReader.py", line 44, in <module>
    BarcodeReader(image)
File "c:\Users\galax\Documents\barcodeScanner\barcodeReader.py", line 12, in BarcodeReader
    detectedBarcodes = decode(img)
File "C:\Users\galax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 207, in decode        
    pixels, width, height = _pixel_data(image)
File "C:\Users\galax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 173, in _pixel_data   
    pixels, width, height = image
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

this is my code:

```
# Importing library
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

# Make one method to decode the barcode
def BarcodeReader(image):
    
    # read the image in numpy array using cv2
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    
    # Decode the barcode image
    detectedBarcodes = decode(img)
    
    # If not detected then print the message
    if not detectedBarcodes:
        print("Barcode Not Detected or your barcode is blank/corrupted!")
    else:
        # Traverse through all the detected barcodes in image
        for barcode in detectedBarcodes:
        
            # Locate the barcode position in image
            (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
            
            # Put the rectangle in image using
            # cv2 to highlight the barcode
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x-10, y-10),
                        (x + w+10, y + h+10),
                        (255, 0, 0), 2)
            
            if barcode.data!="":
            
            # Print the barcode data
                print(barcode.data)
                print(barcode.type)
                
    #Display the image
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
# Take the image from user
    image="barcode.png"
    BarcodeReader(image)
```

and this is barcode.png:
[image: barcode.png]

i have already tried uninstalling and installing pyzbar, but i didnt had any succes either...

any help would be appreciated

Comment: hint: `print(os.getcwd()); assert os.path.exists(image)`

Comment: oh, the barcode was corrupted tho...